# current flow through the terminal to the earth and the battery get discharged?

Tags: batteries

If the positive terminal of a 28volt dc battery is connected to the ground i.e.earth will the current flow through the terminal to the earth and the battery get discharged?

Comment: What is the negative terminal connected to?

Comment: connect a lightbulb to the positive terminal and see if it lights up

Answer (score 0):

For current to flow in any circuit there should be a return path.Here you just connected the +ve terminal of battery to the ground but negative terminal is not connected anywhere so no current will flow.

Comment: Andy's comment was prompting the OP to think this out for him/herself.